# Why QtCreator (qmake) links to different libraries than the ones listed on Kit's Qt version?

Tags: c++, linux, qt-creator, qmake, qt6

I am trying to compile my Qt application and package it for distribution on QtCreator using qmake.

I have a single Kit, configured (whole config details on the table below) to link to the Qt libraries on my home folder, and still, once I compile it, it gives me the system libraries on `ldd`

How can I force Qt Creator to link with the Qt libraries that I configured it to, and not the system's?

**ldd output**

```
$ ldd proprietary_file_reversing2 | grep Qt

libQt6Widgets.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Widgets.so.6 (0x00007fc5863c2000)
libQt6Gui.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Gui.so.6 (0x00007fc585bd9000)
libQt6Core.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Core.so.6 (0x00007fc5856a3000)
libQt6DBus.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6DBus.so.6 (0x00007fc584d8a000)
```

**Kit's configuration on QtCreator**

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| ABI: | x86-linux-generic-elf-64bit |
| Source: | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64 |
| mkspec: | linux-g++ |
| qmake: | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake |
| Version: | 6.5.0 |
| QMAKE_SPEC | linux-g++ |
| QMAKE_VERSION | 3.1 |
| QMAKE_XSPEC | linux-g++ |
| QT_HOST_BINS | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64/bin |
| QT_HOST_DATA | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64 |
| QT_HOST_LIBEXECS | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64/libexec |
| QT_HOST_LIBS | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64/lib |
| QT_HOST_PREFIX | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64 |
| QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64 |
| QT_INSTALL_BINS | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64/bin |
| QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION |  |
| QT_INSTALL_DATA | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64 |
| QT_INSTALL_DEMOS | /home/XXX/Qt/6/Examples/Qt-6.5.0 |
| QT_INSTALL_DOCS | /home/XXX/Qt/6/Docs/Qt-6.5.0 |
| QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES | /home/XXX/Qt/6/Examples/Qt-6.5.0 |
| QT_INSTALL_HEADERS | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64/include |
| QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64/libexec |
| QT_INSTALL_LIBS | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64/lib |
| QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64/plugins |
| QT_INSTALL_PREFIX | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64 |
| QT_INSTALL_QML | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64/qml |
| QT_INSTALL_TESTS | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64/tests |
| QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS | /home/XXX/Qt/6/6.5.0/gcc_64/translations |
| QT_SYSROOT |  |
| QT_VERSION | 6.5.0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qmake` generates `Makefile` according to `mkspecs`, gcc does linking according to instruction in `Makefile`, inspect `Makefile` to verify that linking instructions are correct.

As far as I know binaries does not contain path to linked libraries, only library names, so only way for `ldd` to know exact path is to look for libraries in `$PATH` variable, which means that `ldd` can lie to you if `$PATH` during compilation is different from the `$PATH` during executing `ldd`.

Another way to put it: when `ldd` says app is linked to `libQt6Widgets.so.6` - it is a fact, but when it says `libQt6Widgets.so.6` is `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Widgets.so.6` - it's a guess.

Comment: Damn... Did not think about that from ldd, of course it cannot tell which PATH was used during compilation and can only tell which PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH the executing user has, makes sense... Still, something bizarre is happening and I think might be my environment. Will try on a clean box and see if the same happens

Comment: In the end the actual problem was all the behind-the-scenes paths that QtCreator adds that I could not override, and a weird environment. But your point led to figuring it out.